# Duplicate record insertion in server database using POST request in ios

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios5

```
-(void) registerintoserverDB{
NSString *str_registerURL = @"reg_action.php";

NSString *str_completeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", str_global_domain, str_registerURL]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str_completeURL];  

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 

NSString *str_address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", txt_address1.text, txt_address2.text];   

NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rest_name=%@&rest_telephone=%@&rest_email=%@&rest_password=%@&rest_country=%@&rest_city=%@&rest_postal=%@&rest_delivery=%@&rest_address=%@&rest_image=%@&rest_minimum_order=%@&isUser=%@&fb_name=%@fb_like", txt_restaurantname.text, txt_telephone.text, txt_email.text, txt_pass.text, txt_country.text, txt_city.text, txt_postal.text, txt_deliveryHours.text,  str_address, @"imagepath", @"10 euro", @"Yes", str_global_user_fbUsername];  

NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
[theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 

[theRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];  

NSURLConnection *sConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
[sConnection start];   

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"response data is %@", responseData);  

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString....%@",returnString);
NSDictionary *response_dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSLog(@"msg is  : %@ ",[response_dic objectForKey:@"msg"]);}
```

I want to insert user details into server side database, so i used this piece of code it works fine but the problem is that in my server database duplicate entries are getting inserted like 2 records with same details am unable to recognize where is the problem exactly in my code side or at server end. Please suggest some guidelines as soon as possible.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Remove either:

```
NSURLConnection *sConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
[sConnection start];
```

or this:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Even though you have one request, you're making two distinct connections (one of them is doing an asynchronous connection, the other one is synchronous).  Both together equal two inserts to your database.

Comment: You are a life saver man !! Your suggestion helped me fixed a weird issue with notifications that I was trying to fix from days. Thanks man !!